# Incorrect data from Facebook Share button

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-opengraph

for test i use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ site gmk.ru, but data loaded from site amobile-studio.ru

[image: example]

site gmk.ru contains another content.
iam use open graph properties on news page (share have only this page), example: http://gmk.ru/news/view/id/826
but the data is still not correct

Comment: Your site seems to contain no Open graph meta tags whatsoever – which means, the FB scraper will try and guess what might be the relevant content. If it guesses wrong or you don’t like which pieces of information it picks – then specify them explicitly, by implementing OG meta tags.

Comment: i added OG meta tags. and cleared cache (vk.com and facebook.com). but i  still get incorrect data. scrape get data not from gmk.ru. he get it from other website. i dont know why

Comment: Looks like the FB scraper gets served different content for some reason. If your server/domain is reachable via IPv6, then check if those settings are o.k. (Facebook prefers IPv6 over v4 to connect to websites, and often problems like this stem from people not having their IPv6 set up correctly.)

Comment: I found solution. The problem in hosting.